# What are vegan ways to change or neutralize the taste of textured vegetable protein (TVP)?

Tags: flavor, vegetables, vegan, tasting

I find the taste unappealing. For one cup of TVP I blend 3-4 onions, a head of garlic then add some spices, add carrots, then bake it as burgers and still I can taste it. I tried soaking it in vegetable broth and veggie cubes but I didn't like their taste.

Edit: I'm particularly interested in improving TVP taste or at least neutralizing it.

Comment: Blending onions can surprisingly introduce bitterness. Is there a strong umami source in your mixture (eg yeast in the broth), as well as sugar and some fat?

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind, I have to blend them because this way they last longer. I don't use broth, used it once, didn't like it. So it's usually just onions, garlic and spices.

Comment: Uh no, blended onion paste spoils quicker than whole onions. Try adding some soy sauce (shiitake soy sauce is best here) or MSG, sugar, and fat.

Answer (score 4):

Some might object that this is "not answering the question" but:

If you find that TVP tastes objectionable, try moving on to a felafel recipe (instead of using TVP) if you are looking for a protein rich vegan "patty." (Yes, you can make felafel pattys rather than balls. And you can bake them.) Pretty close to "use soaked, ground/chopped beans/peas/lentlls rather than TVP" in your current approach/recipe. Instead of trying to cover up a flavor you object to, start with a different flavor.

I have used many different types of dry beans or split peas, soaked overnight, coarsely ground or food processed, and turned them into baked pattys. So far they all worked, though of course the taste and color vary between using green split peas, yellow ones, or chickpeas, etc. And can vary further with other vegetable/fruit additions (apple and onion work well, for me.)

I have not used kidney beans and I suppose they might be a poor idea with the toxin that has to be boiled strongly to inactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried textured pea protein?  Much better taste.  Also rehydrated TVP has a super short shelf life, like 3 days, before it begins to smell and taste sour.